# Changing all urls at once and automatic 301 redirection

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

I have a lot of posts on my site, and I want to add the number “1” to the end of the URLs of all my posts at once, and I also want RankMath automatic 301 redirection from the previous URLs to the new URLs, how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First you update your permalink structure inside the Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks. Modify the permalink structure add the number “1” to the end of the URL. This is for your first issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WP CLIs `wp db search-replace` method, with the `--regex` flag.

```
wp search-replace 'https://example.com/([^/]+)/?$' 'https://example.com/$1/1' --regex --all-tables
```

This should roughly be your WP CLI command.

Make sure to do `wp db export` first to save a copy of your DB incase this does not work as expected.

DOCs: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Note: this will only replace your URLs, not change any logic. So Wordpress might not find the pages anymore, without implementing some logic like the one explained by the user Free Helper's solution.